# grouping max values per month

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table with values in the following columns: low, medium, high and month.
I would like to get the following results the max values per month.It will grab the max value in each column per month.

Here is my statement

```
SELECT MAX(low) as Low,MAX(medium) as Medium,MAX(high) as High,month as mth FROM tablename WHERE month > 0;
```

Desired result would be

`month 1: Low 2 Medium 3 High 4`

`month 2: Low 4 Medium 2 High 5`

`month 3: Low 6 Medium 3 High 6`

Comment: Use GROUP BY.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Manual: [`GROUP BY` (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Also, why aren't you storing month as a `date` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(low) as Low,MAX(medium) as Medium,MAX(high) as High,month as mth 
FROM tablename 
WHERE month > 0
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```